# Does it cost more gas to call a function more than once in another function?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, gas, gas-price, design-patterns

Does it cost more gas to call a function more than once in another function?

For example:

```
function getValue() public returns(uint){
    return 5;
}

function getOtherValue() public returns(uint){
    require(getValue() < 6, "Error:Too much");
    require(getValue() > 4, "Error:Too little");
    return getValue() -1;
}
```

Does this other `getOtherValue()` function below use less gas, the same gas or even more gas than the one above?

```
function getOtherValue() public returns(uint){
    uint gottenValue = getValue();
    require(gottenValue < 6, "Error:Too much");
    require(gottenValue > 4, "Error:Too little");
    return gottenValue -1;
}
```

Comment: if you optimize it, it will inline it and no additional cost. but if you call a function in another contract, the overhead will be about 9000 gas for `CALL` instruction

Comment: What do you mean by optimize it? All this functions are called within the same contract.

Comment: `solc --optimize`

Comment: Where should I run this command, I using remix to run these smart contracts.

Comment: i am not using remix, I am using `solc` and Golang

Comment: I have just seen the the functionality on remix. Thanks for your help.